# Android Google Login - Not work on some devices

Tags: android, google-signin, trello

I had an issue relating to Google Login on Android. I have followed Google tutorial as below but it doesn't work on some devices as Galaxy Note 7.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

dataApplication.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

The reason when I debug that is `resultCode = 0` (CANCEL) in callback function:

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

[image]
However, when I test on Trello application, it works well, the login pop-up seems be different:

[image]

Does anyone know how Trello uses Google Login on their app, and how can I fix this bug on my app.

Thank you!

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Did you use release fingerprints to configure google services to API console?

Comment: I added more code as above